# Shapes.AddTextbox being placed at wrong position in Word doc after the first page

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am having this weird issue when I am trying to add textboxes in a Word document from an Excel file. Textboxes are being placed in a loop in all the pages which all contain a table. When I run the code, the first textbox is placed correctly but when I increment to go to next page (where there is a table), the textbox is placed at incorrect position.

I noticed that when I remove the table element the code works fine and all textboxes are placed correctly but when I add back the table, the first page comes out fine but the subsequent pages textboxes are placed incorrectly. Below is an example:
[image]
[image]

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Public Sub test9()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim box As Object

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\user\Downloads\Test2.docx")
objWord.Visible = True

For i = 1 To 10
        objWord.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:=i
        Set doc = objWord.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 53, 130, 20)
        doc.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter "Test Box" & i
Next i
End Sub
```

To reproduce the error you can create a tables in multiple pages and if you run, you'll see the output as shown in the picture.

I am not sure what is causing this or if I am missing anything, please point it out.

Comment: Why text boxes from Excel? Can’t Word create textboxes?

Comment: @SolarMike macro is in Excel file that reads some data from cells and puts it in Word document.

Comment: So is the data the issue or the text boxes?

Comment: @SolarMike data is fine. When I am placing the text boxes it is being placed at incorrect location from 2nd page onwards in the word document.

Comment: Do you have doc declared somewhere else? - or do you mean to use objDoc? In any case it sounds like it's an Anchor problem - maybe you can specify the page as a range and assign it to the textbox anchor parameter? I can come up with an example if that doesn't make sense

Comment: @dbmitch thanks for the response. Thats the whole sub and doc is only refered there. I never encountered the anchor property in the documentation on it. If you can give an example or point out somewhere maybe I can check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me - get the range of the page you want - then anchor the textbox shape to it.

I tested it in Word - you'll have to modify to match your object declarations

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objTextBox As Object ' TextBox Shape
    Dim objRge As Object ' Word Object Range

    For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
        Set objRge = ActiveDocument.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:=i)
        Set objRge = objRge.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")

        ' next you specify the page range as your textbox anchor parameter
        Set objTextBox = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 53, 130, 20, Anchor:=objRge)
        objTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter "Test Box" & i
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you're running from inside Excel and don't have a reference to Word, you'll need to predefine the Word constants - try this

```
Option Explicit

Const TestDoc As String = "C:\Users\<yourusername>\Documents\Test2.docx"


Public Sub TestFromExcel()

    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    
    Dim box As Object
    
    ' Define Word constants in Excel if you don't have a reference to WORD
    Const wdGoToAbsolute    As Long = 1
    Const wdStatisticPages  As Long = 2
    Const wdGoToPage        As Long = 1
    Const wdGoToBookmark    As Long = -1
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(TestDoc)
    objWord.Visible = True

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objTextBox As Object ' TextBox Shape
    Dim objRge As Object ' Word Object Range

    For i = 1 To objDoc.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
        Set objRge = objDoc.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Name:=i)
        Set objRge = objRge.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page")
        Set box = objDoc.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 53, 130, 20, Anchor:=objRge)
        box.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter "Test Box" & i
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it and found only textboxes 1, 6, 7, 8 and 9 were placed correctly on the desirec location. Just curious, do you have table defined in your pages? If you remove those table and run it in say, blank document it will work fine. Just not on the page where it has tables or maybe some other elements.

Comment: I think I found the issue. If I run the code in Word macro then its running fine but if I run it through Excel, it is creating this issue. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: I have tables on each of the only 3 pages in my test document - but I run it from Word. It should work regardless of tables on page. I can't see why Excel would be different.

Comment: Ahhh - I think I see an issue. I can't tell from your code but t looks like you don't have "Option Explicit" defined - that's why you didn't get any errors using the doc variable - AND it also means your Word constants will all be 0. I'll post an Excel example showing how to use Word constants in Excel

Comment: Okay - added Excel example and tested - make sure you have those Word constants defined

Comment: Glad you got it working - that "Option Explicit" at the top will save you hours of troubleshooting in the future

Comment: Not sure what happened, but the above is no longer working. Everything is defined and I tested it in fresh Excel workbook. This is happening only when there are tables defined in word pages. Any advice/suggestion why this happening? No idea how it worked the other day..

Comment: Open a new question and show new code. Do you have Option Explicit at top - and does it compile?